# jquery form submit in new window

Tags: jquery

I am new to jquery to sorry for the easy question. I am trying to submit a form which has two submit buttons...

```
<input id="submitBtn" name="action" value="view" type="submit" class="ym-button ym-primary" value="<spring:message code="button.view"/>" title="<spring:message code="button.view" />" />                                
<input id="saveBtn" name="action" value="save" type="submit" class="ym-button ym-warning" value="<spring:message code="button.save"/>" title="<spring:message code="button.save" />" />
```

As you can see I have a button named submitBtn and saveBtn. The submitBtn returns html whilst the saveBtn returns a pdf.

When submitBtn is hit I would like the form to be submitted normally and have the response load in the current window. But when the saveBtn is hit I would like the current window to remain as is and have the pdf loaded in a new popup window.

So far I have tried...

```
$("#submitBtn").click(function(){ 
    if ($("form[name='shortsAndOversDailyForm']").valid()) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}); 

$("#saveBtn").click(function(){ 
    if ($("form[name='shortsAndOversDailyForm']").valid()) {
        // specify a unique target name
        var target = 'windowFormTarget';
        // open a new window and name it
        window.open('', target, 'width=1400,height=900');
        // set the target of the form to be
        // the window name
        this.setAttribute('target', target);
        // allow the form to be submitted normally
        return true;
    }
    return false;
});
```

The problem with this is that when I hit the save button it opens a new window with no content and the pdf is loaded in the window where the form was submitted.

Can someone help on on how to fix this please so I can have the pdf loaded in the popup window?

thanks

Comment: How are you genereting the pdf?

Comment: Yeah.. . Please indicate or explain what you use or how you generate PDF for us to help you.

Answer (score 1):

`this` is the button and buttons do not have targets, the form does.

```
this.setAttribute('target', target);
```

so you probably want `this.form`

```
this.form.setAttribute('target', target);
```

or using jQuery

```
$(this).closest("form").attr('target', target);
```

---

```
$("#saveBtn").click(function(){
    var form = $("form[name='shortsAndOversDailyForm']");
    if (form.valid()) {
        var target = 'windowFormTarget';
        window.open('', target, 'width=1400,height=900');
        //this.form.setAttribute('target', target);
        form.attr('target', target);
        return true;
    }
    return false;
});
```

Comment: sorry to ask. But you could be a bit more specific with how to function would look like. I've tried this out unsuccessfully. thanks

Comment: What happened? You should just replace the top line with one of the other two.

Comment: thank you for that. I tried to closest option but couldn't get it working. What you have given works well however it looks like this has permanently changed the target of the form. And now when I click on my #submitBtn there is a new window that opens. I've tried to fix this by having exactly the same sort of function for the #submitButton but instead of target=windowFormTarget I say target = '_self'. But this doesn't work. I still get it #submitBtn opening in new window. How can i fix this?

Comment: So you remove the target on the other click of the button. There is no way to make it temporary. `$(this).closest("form").removeAttr("target");`